# How can return a view from another action in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, view, stimulsoft

I have 3 methods (PrintPersonsById, PrintPage, Print) in one controller (ReportsController) in Admin area. first I should call PrintPersonsById method (Through Ajax) and generate a list to prepare to print. then i should redirect to PrintPage action method. and finally, I should return View("PrintPage") that i use stimulsoft to show the report that call Print method. but the "return View("PrintPage")" code not working for me! And I can't go to the PrintPage view And see the print page. plz help me how i can solve this problem? Where am I wrong?
thanks

```
[Area(nameof(Admin))]
public class ReportsController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> PrintPersonsById(string personsId=null)
    {
        if (personsId==null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(personsId))
        {
            _message.SetMessage(Utilities.Errors.MessageType.DANGER, "not selected any record");
            return Json(_message);
        }
        List<int> personsArrayId = new List<int>();
        personsArrayId = personsId.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToList();
        var listToPrint = await _person.GetAllPerson(personsArrayId);
        if (listToPrint.ToList()==null || listToPrint.ToList().Count<=0)
        {
            _message.SetMessage(Utilities.Errors.MessageType.DANGER, "not exists records to print");
            return Json(_message);
        }
        TempData.Set("ListToPrint",listToPrint.ToList());
        return RedirectToAction("PrintPage","Reports", new { area = "Admin" });
    }

    public IActionResult PrintPage()
    {
        if (TempData.Get<List<PersonClone>>("ListToPrint") ==null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "People", new { area = "Admin" });
        }
        TempData.Keep("ListToPrint");
        return View("PrintPage");
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Print()
    {
        var listToPrint = TempData.Get<List<PersonClone>>("ListToPrint") as List<PersonClone>;
        StiReport stiReport = new StiReport();
        stiReport.Load(StiNetCoreHelper.MapPath(this, "wwwroot/Reports/ReportAllPerson.mrt"));

        stiReport.RegData("AllPerson", listToPrint);
        stiReport.Dictionary.Variables.Add("PersianDate", DateTime.Today.ToShamsiDate());
        stiReport.Dictionary.Variables.Add("ReportTitle", "List of exist people in system");
        return StiNetCoreViewer.GetReportResult(this, stiReport);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `new { area = "Admin" }` pass a parameter called `area` to the method? But neither methods are expecting a parameter. So why would it go in any

Comment: @JamesS PrintPersonsById method work fine. also PrintPage method work fine too. just in the end of PrintPage method i wrote <<return View("PrintPage")>> that not work and i can't see Page that i designed for stimulreport. i want why <<return View("PrintPage");>> not work!!

Comment: Did you place the `PrintPage` view in a location where the [view discovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#view-discovery) is able to find it?

Comment: @user7217806 yea when I type the address in the browser address bar it shows correctly PrintPage view but through <<return View("PrintPage")>> code in PrintPage not work!!

Comment: Which address is it that works to show the PrintPage?

Comment: @user7217806 when i type https://localhost:44363/Reports/PrintPage in the browser and push the enter button it works fine and i can see printpage that I designed. but in my code <<return View("PrintPage");>> it don't work! only when i type address in the browser address bar it works.

Comment: But `return View("PrintPage");` is also executed when you call `PrintPage`, right? So do you mean it works in this one case (opening it in the browser), but not in others (which are they?)? And what exactly do you mean with `does not work`? Is it even executed?

Comment: @user7217806 well yes. when i debug code (i use visual studio 2019)  `return View("PrintPage");` not show any page. i mean it not rout to .chtml file that i designed for action `View("PrintPage");`

Comment: So what is shown instead?

Comment: @user7217806 nothing. when i debug the program it not show any error! and not rout to `View("PrintPage")`

Comment: Which address is it that you use to debug, which does not work?

Comment: @user7217806 my route is  **localhost:/repoers/printpage** (default). when i type this address in my browser i can see `View("PrintPage");` (.chtml). but when i debug program it don't show .chtml

Comment: @user7217806 i have another question (is very very important) in here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61959186/how-use-two-kendo-filter-components-for-nested-kendo-grid-hierarchy
plz help me in this question. it's An important part my project i should solve this problem